# Is there a way to run an mvn site to generate a report for the dependencies created from Tycho maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, report, tycho

I just started working on a large multi-module eclipse-based Tycho maven project with a large number of dependencies. This project predates me and has been in the works for a decade and several dependencies are in need of updating. Is there a way to run an *mvn site* to generate a report for the dependencies created from Tycho maven?

The parent pom includes:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

There are a few special modules that require a defined pom and do not depend on Tycho maven for their creation. I am able to get those particular modules to display their dependencies on the generated site. The other modules (that do not have poms and are dependent on Tycho maven and manifest.mf to generate dependencies) will not display the dependencies on the generated site. After searching for the past two weeks, I could not find a way to do it.

I am hoping someone can:

1. confirm that there is not a way to generate the information for Tycho maven dependencies using mvn site; or
2. give a suggestion/experience on how to make mvn site work for my particular situation; or
3. point me in a direction where I can get similar information.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a manifest driven build or a pom driven build for the OSGi components?

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, thank you for responding quickly. It is a manifest driven build for the OSGi components.

Comment: Hi, I have no experience with `mvn site` but if you can't get a satisfactory answer on SO you may want to submit your question to the [tycho-user](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/tycho-user) mailing list.

Comment: Dependencies in Maven and in OSGi are different things. Tycho requires Eclipse p2 repositories, since Maven repositories do not contain the necessary metadata for this (think about how to resolve dependencies via `Import-Package`). In Eclipse there are in addition products and features that also have dependencies. In the p2 repository there is a `content.jar` and an `artifacts.jar` file which each contain an XML file. These XML files contain all metadata and can be used to create a report via XSLT.